# PHP Form without additional File

Tags: php, forms, postback

Is it possible to to have a PHP form without having a seperate file,

e.g. Normal Form

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
```

But instead of calling `send.php` have the code held in `send.php` in the same file as the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just supply the `action` attribute with an empty action

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

or with a `$PHP_SELF` call.

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
```

Both will submit to the current page.

Comment: you can also use <input type="hidden" name="from" value="submit_form"> and use case blocks to further specify conditions on what post actions to take when the php is reloaded